# System.out.println() breaks my if statement

Tags: java, game-engine

I'm making the game dots, were you draw dots, connect them to make boxes. I have it so once you've clicked, the line follows your mouse. When you click on another dot it drops it there. When you add the println code in the if statement, the line no longer follows the mouse.

I have the following code:

```
public void run() {
    gp.initialize();
    while(isRunning) {
        if(gp.isLineDrag()) {
            previousTimeMil = System.nanoTime();
            update();
            draw();
            currentTimeMil = System.nanoTime();

        }
    }
}
```

Update: Sorry, here are the examples

This won't work,

```
public void run() {
    gp.initialize();
    while(isRunning) {
        if(gp.isLineDrag()) {
            System.out.println("Hi");
            previousTimeMil = System.nanoTime();
            update();
            draw();
            currentTimeMil = System.nanoTime();

        }
    }
}
```

This will work

```
public void run() {
    gp.initialize();
    while(isRunning) {
        System.out.println("I work now!");
        if(gp.isLineDrag()) {
            System.out.println("Hi");
            previousTimeMil = System.nanoTime();
            update();
            draw();
            currentTimeMil = System.nanoTime();

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for all the help, hopefully next time I can ask a proper question.

Comment: Include the print statement that is 'breaking' your loop.

Comment: Also, could you actually clarify what you mean by 'breaking' your if statement?

Comment: Include the code with the print statement that breaks the code

Comment: What do you mean "between"? Like `if (System.out.println(gp.isLineDrag())`?

Comment: Could you be more specific than "the if statement won't work"?

Comment: You need to be more careful with your questions. Questions should always show the actual and expected behaviors, along with any specific error message. "Doesn't work" is the statement that makes me skip to the next question

Comment: I also would like to see the print statement, and what kind of "breaking" is being done. Does the program shut down? Is this in a Try/Catch block?

Comment: You have to describe what is not worked.

Comment: Updated, sorry sorry, hopefully that helps explain it

Comment: This looks like a pretty frequently-run bit of code. Could the problem just be that the println is too much of a performance hit?

Comment: To debug this code just define what's the output of the second version.

Comment: gp.isLineDrag() Is this if statement returning false?

Comment: @ jack; I wouldn't think so, because if I add another line of println above the if statement it works just fine.

@ Saviour; it returns true while the println statement isn't there

Comment: You've been asked 5 times what you mean by "it does work" and "it doesn't work", and you still haven't explained anything. What do you expect the code to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: What is gp? That could be a problem. Also, you could change your print statements to print the result of gp.isLineDrag() to help debug.

Comment: @Roman; I tried to add the (!isLineDrag) and put a println in it and the whole thing starts working again. If I take out the println in the (!isLineDrag) the (isLineDrag) stops working again

Comment: What does isLineDrag() return? Anything to do with time?

Comment: No, i don't like to think like you, prefer to trace it.

Comment: @JB; I explained it at the top of my post, sorry if it's not terribly clear :(

@Saviour; gp points to gamePanel. I'm looking through it right now making sure everything is fine.

Comment: @Jack M; isLineDrag() returns a boolean that is true if the mouse is clicking on a dot. And returns false if clicked on dot next to the one selected.

Comment: @Perception; Sorry, I used the wrong word, I realize that now. The if loop just doesn't catch anymore if I add that println statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem that often trips up people. You are running your program from Eclipse or a similar IDE that captures `System.out` into a text area. This capturing and updating of the text area is **incredibly slow** and totally burries your performance, making your realtime graphics routine fail to produce the desired timing-sensitive behavior. Therefore, either run from the command line or write to a file if starting from Eclipse.

Comment: I really wish this was the issue. I just tried writing to a text file and I couldn't get it to work. The line doesn't fallow the mouse when I click on a dot, but as soon as I take out the write to file bits it works again.

Comment: Hmm... I take back what I said, I think this is the issue. It works when I'm in debug. Thanks!